# How to access memory-mapped registers in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a custom hardware device on PCIe bus that has a number of 32-bit configuration registers.  The device driver exposes those registers as a special file in /dev on my Linux system.  A typical approach to accessing these configuration registers in C would be to get a pointer to the device itself, and use it as the base address with the desired register number as an offset, and de-reference that location, like so:

```
fd = open("/dev/my_device", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
void *map_base = mmap(0, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
uitnt32_t offset = 3; 
// read register value
uint32_t volatile value = *((uint32_t *) (map_base + offset));
// write value to register
offset = 5;
uint32_t new_value = 0x11;
*((uint32_t *) (map_base + offset)) = new_value;
```

Now, I'm trying to do this in Rust.  This is my attempt at doing this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::error::Error;

pub struct RegFile {
    pub dev_name: String,
    pub file: File,
}

impl RegFile {
    pub fn new(name: &String) -> Result<RegFile, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let file = File::open(name)?;

        let dev_name = name.clone();
        Ok(RegFile {dev_name, file})
    }

    pub fn read(&self, offset: isize) -> u32 {
        let reg_base = &self.file as *const u32;
        unsafe { *(reg_base.offset(offset)) }
    }
}
```

Compiler is not happy with this cast:

```
error[E0606]: casting `&File` as `*const u32` is invalid
  --> src/reg_file.rs:18:24
   |
18 |         let reg_base = &self.file as *const u32;
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am stuck here.  How does one access these registers in Rust?

Comment: `File::open` isn't going to give you a memory-mapped segment, much like `open(2)` will only give you a file descriptor in C. Consider [this](https://docs.rs/memmap/0.6.2/memmap/struct.Mmap.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your C code included a call to `mmap`, but you did not include the equivalent in Rust.

You can use the [`memmap`](https://docs.rs/memmap/0.7.0/memmap/) crate to provide a Rusty solution. This crate allows you to map a file into a segment of memory which you can then treat like a `[u8]` (an array of bytes).

```rust
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::path::Path;
use memmap::MmapMut;


fn main() {
    
    let file = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .open(Path::new("/dev/mydevice")).unwrap();

    let mut map = unsafe { MmapMut::map_mut(&file).unwrap() };

    // Now you can use map like a slice of u8
    map[0] = 0xff;

}
```